# Unable to read multiple yaml files in zipped folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyyaml

I want to read multiple yaml files containing in two zipped folders. The zipped folder contains nested folders.

The directory structure is as below:

```
C:
- file1.zip
  - aa
    - bb
      - cc
        - x.yaml
        - y.yaml
        - z.yaml
- file2.zip
  - aa
    - bb
      - cc
        - x.yaml
        - y.yaml
        - z.yaml
```

I am unable to read the yaml files within the zipped folder. I am getting error as File Not Found Exception even though the file is present.

I have pasted the code below.

```
def yaml_as_dict(filename):
    my_dict = {}
    with open(filename, 'r') as fp:
        docs = yaml.safe_load_all(fp)
        for doc in docs:
            for key, value in doc.items():
                my_dict[key] = value
    return my_dict

def extract_file1(file1):
    with zipfile.ZipFile(file1) as zip:
        text_files = zip.namelist()
        for t in text_files:
            print(t)
            yaml_as_dict(t)


def extract_file2(file2):
    with zipfile.ZipFile(file2) as zip:
        text_files = zip.namelist()
        for t in text_files:
            print(t)
            yaml_as_dict(t)
```

Comment: Being inside a zipped folder is not the same as being a real file — despite what your OS may lead you to think. You will need to extract each file and then process it.

Comment: note that if you're using pyyaml, `.load()` and `.safe_load()` already create a dict, so there's no need to make another!

Answer (score 0):

As I said in a comment, the members of the .zip archive must first be extracted (and uncompressed) into a actual file order to apply your `yaml_as_dict()` function to them. You also don't need to have a different `extract()` function for each filename when the only thing different between it the name of the file being process.

The code below illustrates how all of these things can be done:

```
import os
from pprint import pprint
from tempfile import TemporaryDirectory
import yaml
import zipfile


def yaml_as_dict(filename):
    my_dict = {}
    with open(filename, 'r') as fp:
        docs = yaml.safe_load_all(fp)
        for doc in docs:
            for key, value in doc.items():
                my_dict[key] = value
    return my_dict


def extract_files(zip_file_path):
    """Extract YMAL files from zip file and convert them to Python dicts."""
    with TemporaryDirectory() as tempdir:
        with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_file_path) as zip:
            for mbr_info in (info for info in zip.infolist() if not info.is_dir()):
                # Extract (and print) data from yaml files.
                if os.path.splitext(mbr_info.filename)[1].lower() == '.yaml':
                    tmpfile_path = zip.extract(mbr_info, path=tempdir)
                    print(f'=> Contents of {mbr_info.filename!r}:')
                    as_dict = yaml_as_dict(tmpfile_path)
                    pprint(as_dict, width=90)
                    print()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    zip_file_path1 = r'C:\path\to\YAML_Files1.zip'
    extract_files(zip_file_path1)
```